# Problem in multiselect list. List is not getting populated

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a vf page where i have country(picklist> and geography(mutiselect list).
When i am selecting from Country, nothing is getting populated in the geography list box. Please let me know where i am doing wrong.

Apex Class -

```
public class ControllerExtension2 {

public string model{get;set;}
public List<String> SelectedDept{get;set;}
public List<Geography__c> results{get;set;}
public List<SelectOption> AllDept{get;set;}
public List<SelectOption> AllName{get;set;}
public List<String> SelectedName{get;set;}

public ControllerExtension2 (){

AllDept= new List<SelectOption>();
AllDept= getDept();
AllName= new List<SelectOption>();
AllName= getName();
}

 public List<SelectOption> getDept()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult departfield =  RFP__c.Country__c.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklist = departfield.getPicklistValues();
        for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : picklist){      
        options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
        }    
        return options;

     }

       public List<SelectOption> getName()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        Set<String> sProj = new Set<String>();

        if(SelectedDept != null && SelectedDept.size()>0)
            {
               for(String oSelectOption : SelectedDept)
               {
                    sProj.add(oSelectOption);
               }
               for(Geography__c Proj  :[select Id, Canonical_Name__c, Type__c from Geography__c where status__c = 'active' AND country__c IN : sProj  order by Canonical_Name__c] )
               {
                    options.add(new SelectOption(Proj.ID,Proj.Canonical_Name__c));
               }

            }

        return options;

     }

   public void FindAllName()
    {
        //AllName= new List<SelectOption>();
        AllName= getName();
    }  

}
```

VF Page -

```
<apex:page controller="ControllerExtension2">
<apex:form id="theForm">
<apex:pageBlock id="theFilterPageBlock">
 <apex:panelGroup >
                                <apex:panelGrid columns="2">

                                    <apex:outputLabel value="Country" for="DPList" style="font-weight:bold;margin-left:145px;"></apex:outputLabel>
                                     <apex:selectList value="{!SelectedDept}" multiselect="false" title="Department" id="DPList" size="1" style="min-width:300px;width:auto;margin-left:12px;" >
                                   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!FindAllName}" reRender="theForm" status="actStatusId">

                                        </apex:actionSupport>
                                       <apex:selectOptions value="{!AllDept}" ></apex:selectOptions> 
                                    </apex:selectList>
                                </apex:panelGrid>
                        </apex:panelGroup>


                        <apex:panelGroup >
                                <apex:panelGrid columns="2">

                                    <apex:outputLabel value="Geography" for="NameList" style="font-weight:bold;margin-left:40px;"></apex:outputLabel>
                                     <apex:selectList value="{!SelectedName}" multiselect="true" title="ProjName" id="NameList" size="6" style="min-width:300px;width:auto;margin-left:12px;" >
                                       <apex:selectOptions value="{!AllName}" ></apex:selectOptions>
                                    </apex:selectList>

                                </apex:panelGrid>

                        </apex:panelGroup>   
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Try changing the `<apex:actionSupport rerender="theForm" />` to rerender the second picklist, instead of the whole form. It may also be a good idea to make sure that the event you are trying to catch to update the form is firing correctly.

Comment: Hi Battery.cord.. If i change size="1" to size="6".. It is working fine..

  <apex:selectList value="{!SelectedDept}" multiselect="false" title="Department" id="DPList" size="1" style="min-width:300px;width:auto;margin-left:12px;" >

Comment: But i need country to be a picklist not a multiselectlist..Can u check plzz.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I think is your issue:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!SelectedDept}" multiselect="false" title="Department" id="DPList" size="1" style="min-width:300px;width:auto;margin-left:12px;" >
```

is bound to Apex controller variable

`public List<String> SelectedDept{get;set;}`

yet, when using a selectList component where `multiselectList` is false, you need to bind to a controller variable of type `String`, not `List<String>`

From the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectList.htm), `value`:

> A merge field that references the controller class variable that is
>   associated with this selectList. For example, if the name of the
>   associated variable in the controller class is myListSelections, use
>   value="{!myListSelections}" to reference the variable. If multiselect
>   is true, the value attribute must be of type String[] or a List of
>   strings. Otherwise, it must be of type String.